# SEP IRA eligibility criteria?

Tags: united-states, ira, retirement, sep-ira

I am trying to determine if I can establish and contribute to a SEP IRA. Here are what I think to be the relevant details and questions.

- I receive a W-2 from my day job employer
- I have side income that involves

  - 1099-MISC income sometimes
  - ad revenue from a website (1099-NEC)
  - k1 pass-through income from a partnership
  - cash income from small hobby projects like teaching lessons or hosting small events

Do any of the preceding income sources qualify for contributions to a SEP IRA?

Answer (score 1):

> I receive a W-2 from my day job employer

Ineligible for a SEP IRA (even if your employer doesn't offer a retirement plan).

> I have side income

I'm answering under the assumption that you're either a sole proprietor or have established a single-member LLC. If you have a different business structure, the following won't apply.

> 1099-MISC income sometimes

If this income is considered self-employment income on Schedule C, yes.

> Ad revenue from a website (1099-NEC)

If this income is considered self-employment income on Schedule C, yes.

> k1 pass-through income from a partnership

Ineligible, unless this income is considered self-employment income and subject to self-employment tax.

> cash income from small hobby projects like teaching lessons or hosting small events

If this income is considered self-employment income on Schedule C, yes.

Note that if you have eligible employees, you must also contribute to their SEP IRAs based on their compensation.